# Instantiating HMHomeManager causes a background thread error

Tags: ios, homekit, ios-homekit

I have a fresh iOS app / project; all I've done is import the HomeKit framework.  When I instantiate `HMHomeManager`:

```
var homeManager = HMHomeManager()
```

Xcode yells at me:

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
```

... this occurs even if I wrap it in `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`

Since this project is effectively blank, I'm assuming this an Xcode bug ... but am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you show more context?  Where are you instantiating the `HMHomeManager`? Which version of iOS and Xcode are you using? I just created a blank single view application in Xcode and instantiated a `HMHomeManager` both as a property with a default value and in `viewDidLoad` and did not have any warnings on background thread.

Comment: @Paulw11 Xcode version 10.1 (10B61) ... iOS 12.1 (16B92) ... doing exactly the same thing you are.

Comment: Hmm.  I am running the same versions. I tested on an iPhone 8+ and an iPhone XR simulator.  No issues. Can you upload your test project somewhere?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having the same issue. Xcode 10.2, iOS 12.2.

Comment: @mark negative -- upvote the question and maybe we'll get an answer some day :/

Comment: The backtrace I get ends up in CoreLocation CLClientStopVehicleHeadingUpdates, called from HomeKit <redacted>.

Comment: Has anyone come up with the solution? I'm facing the same issue...

Comment: I have the same issue, happens on iPhone XS with iOS 12.4. I tried the same app on iPhone 5s with iOS 12.3.1 and there is no such warning. I guess we should ignore it and wait until it's fixed.